# 400 bad request ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, post

I'm running into a weird problem, I want to do a POST request in AJAX with the following code:

```
$('.login-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // to block the behavior from HTML form
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/login",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            username:"lmezkml",
            password:"ezaezaeza"
        }),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('success');
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

Even after following the multiple topics on this problem, i'm still in trouble.
For example, i've tried :

- adding `dataType: 'json'`
- adding `contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8"`
- using `XMLHttpRequest()`
- using `$.post`

The inspector of Chrome give me :

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
**Request Headersview source**
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:45
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
**Request Payloadview source**
{username:lmezkml, password:ezaezaeza}
password: "ezaezaeza"
username: "lmezkml"
**Response Headersview source**
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 09 Dec 2015 14:39:11 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Here is my code from server :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces={"application/json"}, consumes={"application/json"})
public ResponseEntity<?> hello(@RequestParam("name") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    System.out.println("username : " + username + " password : " + password);
    try {
        LdapContext ctx = ActiveDirectory.getConnection(username, password);
        ctx.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        //Failed to authenticate user!
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Hope it can help to resolve my problem of 400 bad request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you debugged on the server to see what the exact cause of the 400 is? My guess would be that you're sending a JSON string and the server is expecting a querystring.

Comment: Send data without stringifying.

Comment: @Jai i've already tried without stringify, it doesnt work

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i've updated my topics with server side route

Answer (score 0):

I think, problem on server.

Try send to server js object, not string, or debug in server.

Comment: Try send to server js object, not string

I dont know this language but i think you use req params, not body.

Send your data in query ( localhost:3000/api/login?name="Alex"&password="qwerty")
Or recived data on server on request body

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem thanks to Alex Repeckiy. The real problem was that the data was stored in Body and ive tried to get them by parameter.

If it can help Spring Framework users, i change my function by using `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`.

Thanks !